# Why no ‘mysql.session’ user in percona:5.7.31 image

Tags: percona

I use this image:
[percona:5.7.31](https://hub.docker.com/layers/percona/library/percona/5.7.31/images/sha256-9c8ac645edf99c63fd0e10e7b1a646492ff88d2606dfa315171e9c5c82abb8e1?context=explore)

```
mysql> select * from mysql.user where user=‘mysql.session’
→ ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

but the community 5.7.31 image has ‘mysql.session’ user,why?

```
mysql> select user from mysql.user where user=‘mysql.session’;
±--------------+
| user |
±--------------+
| mysql.session |
±--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

the percona:5.7.31 not correspond to community:5.7.31??

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug,I asked in the percona forum, they put it on the jira,：https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-7668

there is a hack method: upgrade the cluster